# How can I match the last part of an email via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I stumbled across `(?<=\@)(.*?)(?=\.)` here on StackOverflow, but apparently *possitive lookbehinds* are not supported in **JavaScript**.

I modified it a little to use `/(@)(.*?)(?=\.)/` and I can obtain the last part of an email.

My problem is now trying to extract the *last part* if there are two `.` characters.

**For example:**

```
const[x, y, lastPart]="foo@bar.com".match(/(@)(.*?)(?=\.)/) //lastPart = bar 
const[x, y, lastPart]="foo@mailinator.com".match(/(@)(.*?)(?=\.)/) //lastPart = mailinator
```

These cases work perfectly, but when I try with **`foo@my.domain.com`**, I would like to extract **`my.domain`** and not **`my`**.

Comment: I am not interested in obtaining the `.com`, simply the bits between `@` and `.X`

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/mrj6krp1/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It may be duplicate but as someone who doesn't write regex, the answer in the post I "duplicated" doesn't express where I should put the code.